# CoreData mergeChanges

Tags: swift, core-data, merge

In my old projects, I've set up a Core Data store and model. In this model, I'm using a `NotificationCenter` to observe the `NSManagedObjectContext`. Whenever a context is being saved, it merges with the other contexts:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didSaveContext), name: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave, object: nil)

@objc func didSaveContext(notification: Notification) {
    guard let sender = notification.object as? NSManagedObjectContext else { return }

    if sender === mainContext {
        userContext.perform { self.userContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification) }
        idleContext.perform { self.idleContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification) }
    } else if sender === userContext {
        mainContext.perform { self.mainContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification) }
        idleContext.perform { self.idleContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification) }
    } else if sender === idleContext {
        mainContext.perform { self.idleContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification) }
        userContext.perform { self.idleContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification) }
    } else {
        userContext.perform { self.userContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification) }
        mainContext.perform { self.mainContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification) }
        idleContext.perform { self.idleContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification) }
    }
}
```

But since iOS10, Apple introduced the `NSPersistentContainer` and I'm able to use:

```
persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

Does this mean I don't have to use the notification center to merge the changes anymore?

Comment: Found a pretty good article about this: https://swifting.io/blog/2016/09/25/25-core-data-in-ios10-nspersistentcontainer/?utm_source=swifting.io&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=blog%20post%29

Answer (score -1):

> Does this mean I don't have to use the notification center to merge the changes anymore?

NO, you must implement notification and call `mergeChanges()` to merge changes.